# Number of upvotes incorrectly displayed in android app search

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, vote-count

I have been browsing through the most upvoted questions on Stack Overflow and noticed there is a bug in the number of upvotes for the most popular one:

[image: shiny image of this bug]

At least on the Android app instead of 11k only 1.1k are displayed.

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.1.1, SE app v1.0.68. Considering that the app can display the second most upvoted question without being cut (`7,690`), it seems the error is in the rounding logic.

Comment: @AndrewT.  I believe the problem is in the number of digits.  This is the only question above 10k

Answer (score 2):

As of v1.0.82 (beta), it has been fixed. The app now shows the vote count properly.

[image: it is 13k!]

Comment: Beat me to the punch, thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 1):

### Expected behavior

1,1k is according to my knowledge 1100. But when opening the question it shows a vote count of 11089 which is way more than 1,1K. The correct display value would be 11k or 11,1k (with rounding).

Note that my phone locale is Dutch. Which means that points are used for separating thousands and commas decimals.

### Proposed fix

**Method one: decimal point when the K postfix is used and the number is shorter than 3 digits.**

```
public static String format(int votes){
    // Without K
    if(votes < 10000){
        return String.format("%,d", votes);
    }
    // K + 1 decimal
    else if(votes < 100000){
        return String.format("%,.1fK", votes/1000.0);
    }
    // Just K
    return String.format("%,dK", votes/1000);
}
```

Result:

```
1043    >  1.043  
11089   >  11,1K  
100000  >  100K  
1000000 >  1.000K
```

**Method two: no decimals at all** (my favorite).

```
public static String format(int votes){
    if(votes < 10000){
        return String.format("%,d", votes);
    }
    return String.format("%,dK", votes/1000);
}
```

Result:

```
1043    >  1.043  
11089   >  11K  
100000  >  100K  
1000000 >  1.000K
```