# Large tag counts off by a factor of 10 on Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app

For tags with >= 10,000 questions, the tag counts are misrepresented on my StackExchange Android app.
Specifically, they are reduced by a factor of 10.

Here is a screenshot of the highest tag counts on Stackoverflow (website)

[image: Most popular tags, viewed on the website]

And here are the same tags on the Android app:

[image: Most popular tags, viewed on the Android app]

You can see how javascript, for example, has 945,345 questions, but the app displays this as 94.5k.

A related phenomenon: the tags seem to be sorted correctly, it is just that the displayed numbers are wrong; see the following screenshot where numbers "drop" from 1k to 9,950.

[image: Tag counts around the 10,000 limit]

This is on a Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.1 and Stack Exchange Android App version 1.0.73

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue in iOS 1.3.2. Just a note.

Comment: Strangely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259070/number-of-upvotes-incorrectly-displayed-in-android-app-search, I think they're using [Chinese grouping of 10.000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v1.0.82 (beta), it has been fixed. The app now shows the tag count properly.

[image: 100k and above!]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot! [meta-tag:status-complete] added :)