# Questions with 10k+ votes are abbreviated to have 1/10 as many

Tags: bug, voting, search, android-app

In the Android app, I sorted the questions by votes.  The odd thing was that the top result said it had 1.5k votes, but the third said that it had 7,688.  Either that's ordered wrong, or it's displayed wrong.

[image: Search results]

I opened the questions, and it turns out that the questions whose votes round to 10k or more show up in the search results with 1/10 the number of votes.  That "1.5k" question is actually 15k.

[image: actual question]

Comment: The first got 14705 views, the 1.5k is wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Do you mean votes?  I already mentioned that in the question and the title.

Comment: Looks like you're using old version, as it was [fixed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259070/number-of-upvotes-incorrectly-displayed-in-android-app-search).

Comment: Not repro'd on v1.0.85, it has been fixed since v1.0.82 beta.